# intellij IDEA - create android app failed

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When I'm trying to create android application in intellij idea I get the following

```
The project wasn't generated by 'android' tool

: can't find sdkmanager.jar
/Users/timon/development/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/android: line 30: dirname: command not found
/Users/timon/development/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/android: line 33: basename: command not found
/Users/timon/development/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/android: line 40: dirname: command not found
/Users/timon/development/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/android: line 44: dirname: command not found
/Users/timon/development/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/android: line 48: basename: command not found
```

showing the window:

[image: error]

I tried to set up PATH variables locating android SDK but it doesn't help. Android SDK is installed correctly and I can create and run android projects in Eclipse. What am I doing wrong? It seems like very common error. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a path problem. I don't know exactly what's going on but you might want to try opening the app from the command line rather than through Finder. This way it will inherit your PATH - it doesn't when you launch from Finder. In general, even when I don't have problems, I make sure to run Intellij from the command line.

Comment: Great it helped! I can create android app when I start intelliJ from terminal. I'm just curious now - how to fix this PATH problem so I can run intelliJ from spotlight?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with IntelliJ Idea 11 on mac.
Adding export `PATH=/Users/myhomedir/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx:$PATH` and starting idea from command line terminal helped.