# IntelliJ Idea fails to create a new Android application project

Tags: android, eclipse, intellij-idea, windows-7-x64

I am using IntelliJ Idea 12.1.4 Community Edition in Windows 7 which contains Android Support by default.

I can import Android projects which were created using Eclipse and they are working fine in IntelliJ. But when I tried to create a new Android Project in IntelliJ it failed to do so. It is showing a dialog box

> Cannot find resource directory for module [ProjectName]

Then in Android Console:

> The project wasn't generated by 'android' tool.
>
> 'C:\Windows\system32\java.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
>
> Invalid path
>
> ERROR:
> SWT folder '' does not exist.
>
> Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform.

I have tried both answers from the following questions:
[intellij IDEA - create android app failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920400/intellij-idea-create-android-app-failed)
[IntelliJ IDEA 12 - New Android Application Module wizard fails with "cannot find resource directory for module"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16497358/intellij-idea-12-new-android-application-module-wizard-fails-with-cannot-find)
But both answers has failed to solve this.

**Edit:**
Screeshots of SDKs' path in IntelliJ Idea

**JDK Path:**
[image]

**Android SDK Path:**
[image]

Comment: Please add the screenshots showing your JDK and Android SDK configuration in IDEA.

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have added the screenshots of JDK and Android SDK configuration as you request.

Comment: It looks like `android.bat` file is calling `lib\find_java.bat` that is using `lib\find_java.exe` to locate Java installation on your system, but it detects the wrong version. You can reinstall the JDK and define `JAVA_HOME` environment variable that will point to the correct JDK installation directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you @CrazyCoder for your answer as in comment.

I added a new variable in Environment Variables called `JAVA_HOME` with JDK path - `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25` as value.

Now IntelliJ Idea creating new Android Projects successfully.